# Does $\Delta u=f$ if $\{u_i\}$ and $\{f_i\}$ are smooth functions such that $u_i\to u$ in $W^{k+2,p}$, $f_i\to f$ in $W^{k,p}$, and $\Delta u_i=f_i$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, poissons-equation

**Question:** Let $\{u_i\}$ and $\{f_i\}$ be two sequences of functions in $C^\infty$, and suppose that $u_i\to u$ in the Sobolev space $W^{k+2,p}$ and that $f_i\to f$ in $W^{k,p}$. If each $u_i$ solves the Poisson equation $\Delta u_i=f_i$ strongly(omitted hereafter since we won't consider weak solutions), can we conclude that $u$ solves $\Delta u=f$?

**Attempt:** Certainly I could do something if uniform convergence were assumed. But all I have is convergence in the Sobolev spaces. So I turned to
$$\lVert\Delta u-f\rVert_{W^{k,p}}=0$$
for help. Now the triangle inequality gives
$$\lVert\Delta u-f\rVert_{W^{k,p}}\leq\underbrace{\lVert\Delta u-f_i\rVert_{W^{k,p}}}_{(1)}+\underbrace{\lVert f_i-f\rVert_{W^{k,p}}}_{(2)}\ .$$
The second term (2) on the LHS surely converges to zero by hypothesis, and the first term (1) can be written as
$$\lVert\Delta(u-u_i)\rVert_{W^{k,p}}\ .\tag{3}$$
I was trying to use convergence of $\{u_i\}$ to vanquish (3), but nothing useful has ever come into my mind. Is there any problem in my attempt? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't $\Delta : W^{k + 2, p} \to W^{k, p}$ is continuous?

Comment: @Mason Exactly. Since $\Delta$ is linear, it is continuous. Now the result is obvious once we appeal to the sequential definition of continuity. No inequality is needed. Thank you, Mason. You deserve the credit.

Comment: I was wrong. That $\Delta$ is continuous does not follow simply from linearity of $\Delta$. Whether an operator is continuous or not should depend on the topologies of its domain and codomain.

Comment: Yeah the topology of $W^{k, p}$ is such that $\partial_j : W^{k, p} \to W^{k - 1, p}$ is continuous for all $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \dots \}$. Here $\partial_j$ is the distributional $j$th partial derivative.

Comment: @Mason Thank you. I just don't want other people to be misled by me.